# Как в Nextcloud открывать боковую панельку с комментариями при клике на файл?

Tags: nextcloud

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в некстклауде при нажатии на файл сразу появлялась боковая панелька с комментариями. По умолчанию, чтобы она появилась, нужно сначала нажать на иконку меню у файла, потом "Подробнее" и панелька появляется.

Я хочу найти место, где вызывается функция, которая открывает панельку и перенести ее на нажатие на файл.

Но проблема в том, что я не могу найти эту функцию. Нашел саму боковую панельку `SidebarTab.vue`. Нашел, что в `fileactions.js` открывается меню `FileActionsMenu`, в котором ставится темплейт `fileactionsmenu` из `templates.js`. Но где сама функция открытия?

php8.0, NextCloud 25

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#file').click(function() {
   $('#comments-sidebar').toggle();
});
```

Где `#file` - это id файла, а `#comments-sidebar` - это id боковой панели с комментариями.

У меня:

- `comments-sidebar` id - это `app-sidebar-vue` и при вызове `$('#app-sidebar-vue').toggle();` открывает или закрывает комментарии.
- `file` id -fileList

то есть я выполнил

```
$('#fileList').click(function() {
   $('#app-sidebar-vue').toggle();
});
```

И при клике на файл открывает детали. Но проблема в том, что сам Nextcloud выполняет клик тоже и начинает скачивание.

К сожалению, невозможно предоставить готовый код, так как Nextcloud - это комплексное приложение с множеством различных функций.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но почему-то не работает. Пока просто вызываю `$('#app-sidebar-vue').toggle();`. Сначала, почему-то нужно вручную открыть панельку, только потом будет работать toggle. Вы не знаете с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: нет. не могу сказать почему. может быть потому, что компонента app-sidebar-vue еще не существует до первого появления